# How to make second datagrid name visible in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

In XAML, if I create one datagrid, I can assign a name to it and call it within the program. If I create another datagrid after the first one and assign a name such as below, it won't be recognized on the C# side. What do I have to do to make it be recognized in the C# side?

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
          <DataGrid x:Name="secondDataGrid">
          </DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Comment: The real question is why would you?

Comment: Maybe helpful: [How do I access an element of a control template from within code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126700/how-do-i-access-an-element-of-a-control-template-from-within-code-behind)