# Can I Get the VisualStateGroups defined in the XAML from code behind in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, controltemplate, visualstatemanager

I have my XAML code as below.

```
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ThumbnailItem}">
                    <ContentPresenter>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup Name="FocusedStates">
                                <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation To="Red" 
              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

I want to access the defined `VisualStateGroups` from code behind. But the below code `VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups` is always returns null.

```
 ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(this);
 var visualStateGroups = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(myContentPresenter);
```

Is there any good way to achieve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access an element of a control template from within code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126700/how-do-i-access-an-element-of-a-control-template-from-within-code-behind)

Comment: No. I can access the elements, but I need to read the visual state groups and its values present in the same.

Comment: `MyControl.Template.FindName("FocusedStates", MyControl) as VisualStateGroup` does access the `VisualStateGroup`.

Comment: Thank you. This gives the information. I get the VisualState too using the name "Selected".


Meanwhile, Can I get the Color animation inside the VisualState using the object?