# How can I bind this Textblock inside ControlTemplate in button style?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I have a `Button` style and this style contains an icon and a text. I would like to bind the text.
How can I achieve that?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ConnectedButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Padding="5 0" 
                        Width="80"
                        Height="30"
                        Margin="5">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Connect}"  
                                   Margin="3 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ConnectIcon}" 
   
                                   Style="{StaticResource Icon_Text}"  Margin="3 0"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Use the style in `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
  <Button Style="{StaticResource ConnectedButton}" Margin="10,15,0,10" x:Name="cnct_btn" Content="{StaticResource Connect}"  Height="40" Width="80 " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Click="Cnct_Click"/>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
bool test = false;
//...

if (test)
{
   cnct_btn.Content = "Connect";
}
else 
{
   cnct_btn.Content = "Not Connected";
}
```

I have tried `Text={Binding Connect}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `Connect` should be a property in something (view model in MVVM terms) what is accessible via `DataContext` (inherited by `TextBlock` from its container). You haven't show any other bindings, do you have one already? Is `DataContext` propertly set, etc? You can also [access control in style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8126700/1997232) from code-behind, but bindings are better.

Comment: No , I didn't used MVVM , it's just binding to simple variable

Comment: @abdou31: What variable are you trying to "bind" to? Your example is rather confusing.

Answer (score 1):

In a control template, you have to use a [`TemplateBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.templatebindingextension?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.TemplateBindingExtension);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) to access a property on a templated control. In case of a `Button`, it is the `Content` property that you want to bind.

> Implements a markup extension that supports the binding between the value of a property in a template and the value of some other exposed property on the templated control.

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"  
           Margin="3 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

A simple `Binding` will resolve a property on the current data context. You can also make this work, but you need to specify a [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Data.RelativeSourceMode);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) using [`TemplatedParent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Data.RelativeSourceMode);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0).

> `TemplatedParent` - Refers to the element to which the template (in which the data-bound element exists) is applied. **This is similar to setting a `TemplateBindingExtension` and is only applicable if the Binding is within a template**.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"  
           Margin="3 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Please note that in this scenario a `TemplateBinding` is sufficient, [as it is only one way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#remarks). In a two-way binding you would have to use the variant using `RelativeSource` and `TemplatedParent`.

> A `TemplateBinding` is an optimized form of a `Binding` for template scenarios, analogous to a Binding constructed with `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}`. A `TemplateBinding` is always a one-way binding, even if properties involved default to two-way binding. Both properties involved must be dependency properties. In order to achieve two-way binding to a templated parent use the following binding statement instead `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay, Path=MyDependencyProperty}`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have used the architecture MVVM as known ( Model view viewmodel , ) I'm using View, Model and Controllers ( MVC but with binding )

Comment: @abdou31 The template binding is only relevant for transferring the value assigned to the `Content` property to the `TextBlock` inside of the control template. How you assign the `Content` property - be it through a binding, resource reference, code-behind or literal value - does not matter.