# How can i make a dependency property with type List<control> element in UWP

Tags: c#, list, xaml, uwp

I am new to UWP and C# so i hope that somebody can help me.
I am currently trying to make a custom control in UWP but got a problem. My idea is a button to change the theme of the application. For that i want to let the user of my custom control speicify which elements he want the background to change in the XAML-file.

It should look like this (Pseudocode):

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1" Grid.Column="1" Background="Black">
   <Button x:Name="Button1"/>
   <local:ModeSelector Grid.Row="1">
      <local:ModeSelector.Tools>
         <Button1/>
         <Grid1/>
         ... 
      </local:ModeSelector.Tools>

   </local:ModeSelector>
</Grid>
```

My DependencyObject looks like this:

```
public List<Control> Tools
        {
            get { return (List<Control>)GetValue(ToolsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ToolsProperty, new List<Control>()); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Tools", typeof(List<Control>), typeof(ModeSelector), new PropertyMetadata(new List<Control>()));
```

in my c# file i then have a list of controls from which i can change the backgroundcolor. In this example it is "Button1", "Grid1", ... . My question now how can i implement this list in my XAML file?

Thank you in advance

Comment: So what is the real problem, is changing the background of control in a different theme a problem, or is the DependencyProperty binding a problem?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT no the theme is not the problem, my problem is to create a dependency property of type list<control> (or a list of a more fitting type) to give the user the option to specify which controls he wants the background to change in the xaml file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this, but it sounds like what you're trying to do is apply customized themes.

I would give this article a read through: [Custom Themes in UWP Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533783/custom-themes-in-uwp-application)

And this video here: [XAML Themes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/uwp-029-xaml-themes)

Comment: The theme itself is not the problem. My idea is to let the user of my custom control decide which of his controls he wants the theme to change by specifying them in a dependency property list of controls. If the user for example has two grids in his application and only wants to change the background of one of them he can just specify it by writing the name of the grid in the dependency property list of my custom control.

Comment: I dont know if that is even possible but it would be cool. Thank you for your answer btw. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use a list of `string` instead of a list of `Control`. I've tested the `Control` type of list with binding, the databinding will throw exceptions even when you set the **x:DataType** as `Control`. This is an interesting behavior and I'll try to dig a little bit about this to find out the reason.

So currently, you might need to use the name of each control instead if you want to use binding to list all the Controls. Then when you select a control, you could find the control via its name.

Comment: Hmm that sounds interesting but wouldnt i also need to know the type of that control?

Comment: @Sam I think you should know what type of the control when you defined the name of the control in Xaml. What you need to do is to find the controls by name, get the control instance and change its background. You could check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70176721/access-an-element-from-uwp-control-instance-that-has-a-controltemplate-assigned/70210083#70210083) about how to get a control by name